# How to crawl website that requires login in table format using Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to crawl into a website which requires login but in the form there is a table whose html content I have added below and with that I have added my code.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

```
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="background:#FDFDFD;">
                       <tbody><tr>
                           <td colspan="2" align="center">
                               Loyola Students Log In
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" align="center">

                                <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" width="50%" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">

                                    <form id="login_form" name="login_form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                        <input type="hidden" id="txtSK" name="txtSK">
                                                        <input type="hidden" id="txtAN" name="txtAN">
                                                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="_tries">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_md5">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="txtPageAction" id="txtPageAction" value="0">
                                                        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="60%">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td nowrap="" align="right">Your ID (Dept.No.): </td>
                                                                    <td align="left"><input size="17" id="login" name="login"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td nowrap="" align="right">Password:</td>
                                                                    <td align="left"><input type="password" maxlength="32" size="17" value="" id="passwd" name="passwd"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td align="right"><a href="../../students/loginManager/forgotPassword.jsp">Forgot password?</a></td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="_save" id="_save" onclick="funSave()">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
<!--                                                <tr>                                                                    
                                                    <td colspan="1" style="cursor:pointer"  align=center valign=center onclick="javascript:window.open('../../students/loginManager/forgotPassword.jsp')"><u>Forgot Password</u></td>                                                                                                                                                            
                                                </tr>-->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left">
                                                        <p>If you are a Student and this is your first login, you must use your Dept. number as your User ID, with your date of birth [Format ddmmyyyy E.g. 03121990] as your password.</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="28px">
                                                        <div id="divProcess" name="divProcess" style="top : 0; left : 0; height:20px; width:100%;display:none ">
                                                            <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                                                                <tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">Please Wait...<img src="../../resources/Image/wait.gif"></td></tr>
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td></tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
           </tr>

           </tbody></table>
```

So, the above is the inspect element derived code and it has table which has a form and then table elements.
I wish to login and scrape the data and I have written some basic code which is written below.

My code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

from quotes_spider.items import QuotesSpiderItem


class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = (
        'http://erp.loyolacollege.edu/loyolaonline/students/loginManager/youLogin.jsp',
    )

    def parse(self, response):

        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'login': 'abc','password': 'xyz'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_home_page)

    def scrape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        l = ItemLoader(item=QuotesSpiderItem(), response=response)

        h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
        tags = response.xpath('//*[@class="tag-item"]/a/text()').extract()

        l.add_value('h1_tag', h1_tag)
        l.add_value('tags', tags)

        return l.load_item()
```

Comment: form doesn't use `password` but `passwd` - see `name="passwd"` which is used to send data to server. Besides it sends many hidden values which you would have to get from HTML and send to server. If page use JavaScript to calculate some hidden values then it can be problem do it without Selenium which can control web browser to run this JavaScript.

Comment: first use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox an check in tab `Network` what data it sends to server when you login.

Comment: Yes, there are javascript functions written to calculate those hidden values. How should I proceed? @furas

Comment: [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) can control web browser which runs JavaScript and then you can get from HTML calculated values.There is also extension [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)